# Is there a combinatorial interpretation for this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there a combinatorial interpretation for:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{3i}{i}\binom{3(n-i)}{n-i}?$$

I do not think there is a simple closed form for it, like:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2(n-i)}{n-i} = 4^{n}.$$

Several types of combinatorial proofs are given for this identity.

Comment: Where can I find proof for the second sum in OP's question?

Answer (score 2):

A good tool to apply for such problems is the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. I computed the first ten value or so of your function of $n$, searched oeis.org, and found [an entry for the sequence](http://oeis.org/A006256) that contains formulas, asymptotics, references, and so on.